# why while loop get incorrect outcome

Tags: python

The question is: Given positive integer num_insects, write a while loop that prints that number doubled up to, but without exceeding 100. Follow each number with a space.

Input: 8 
Expected output: `8 16 32 64`

but actual output:

```
8
16
32
64
128
```

This is my code

```
num_insects = int(input("")) 

while num_insects <= 100:
   if num_insects > 0:
   num_insects *= 2
   print(num_insects)
```

Comment: because when num is 64, you enter the loop as `num_insects <= 100` is true. then you multiply it by two *first* and then print. So naturally, you see what you see.

Comment: First, you print the `print(num_insects)` outside the `if num_insects > 0:` then execute the syntax `num_insects *= 2`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because when num_insects is 64, the conditional num_insects <= 100 is true. It then is multiplied by two, which is 128 and is then printed. To fix this, you'll want to check if num_insects * 2 is less than 100 like the following:

```
num_insects = int(input("")) 

while num_insects * 2 <= 100:
   if num_insects > 0:
      num_insects *= 2
      print(num_insects)
```

Answer (score 0):

When the loop that prints `128` begins, the value of `num_insects` meets the while-loop criteria. After the loop begins, it is changed.

Does this make sense to you?

Let's look at the final iteration.

```
while num_insects <= 100: # Current value is 64
    if_num_insects >0:    # This is true. 64 is greater than 0
        num_insects *= 2  # Double 64. Now it is 128
    print(num_insects)    # Prints 128
```

At this point, `num_insects <= 100` is no longer true and the loop exits.

Answer (score 0):

Given positive integer num_insects, write a while loop that prints, then doubles, num_insects each iteration. Print values ≤ 100. Follow each number with a space.

Sample output with input: 8
8 16 32 64

```
num_insects = int(input()) # Must be >= 1

while num_insects <= 100:
  print(num_insects, end = ' ')
  num_insects = num_insects *2
```

Answer (score 0):

This was a good challenge activity. Here is the code after the input()

```
while (num_insects <=100):
    if num_insects >= 0:
      print(num_insects, end= ' ')
      num_insects = num_insects * 2
```

Another fun activity was the gambling challenge:
all you need to do is write the while statement to include:
while (keep_going != 'n'):

That was an easy one, figured I would include that just in case someone was pulling out their hair.